# Application process not ending when I close the form? (C#)

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

Experimenting with the TcpClient and TcpListener class and for some reason when I have a couple of threads running and I close the form the process does not end but the form disappears.

I have to manually kill the process with the VS IDE or task manager.

Nothing in the form is still running from what I can tell when I close the program but the process does not end.. I insert breakpoints everywhere and even the console output says the threads exited.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thread of your application is waiting for the threads your spawned to finish. You can set the `IsBackground` property of your threads to `true` so they do not stop your process from terminating:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx):

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.